# javascript class property not set in success function of ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object, asynchronous

*Sorry for the duplication but I can find any solution in the others posts.*

I'm trying to fill a javascript object using a ajax call to a webservice. I don't understand the logic of this and why my object in not set after the call. I wrote this little example to explain my problem :

Code :

```
function Cellule(){
    this.test = 0;
    this.textfunction();
}

Cellule.prototype.textfunction = function(){
    this.test = 1;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "BASEURL/cellules", 
        data: "",
        success: function(msg){
            console.log("success");
            this.test = 2;
            console.log(cellule);
        }
    });
};

var cellule = new Cellule();
```

Console out :

```
success
Cellule {test: 1}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> `this` does not refer to `cellule`

Use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) or [`context`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) in argument of `ajax` settings

*The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value*

Or specifying `context: this` will use context of `cellule` in success handler.

Try this:

```js
function Cellule() {
  this.test = 0;
  this.textfunction();
}

Cellule.prototype.textfunction = function() {
  this.test = 1;
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../slimrest/andon/cellules",
    data: "",
    success: function(msg) {
      console.log("success");
      this.test = 2;
      console.log(cellule);
    }.bind(this)
  });
};

var cellule = new Cellule();
```

Comment: Well done . Work perfectly

Comment: Happy to help! Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the best solution which has solved the purpose :) __Happy coding!__

Answer (score 1):

Your issue gets caused because of the fact that the `this-scope` changed when using the ajax call.

Binding the this scope to the call should solve your issue.

```
function Cellule(){
    this.test = 0;
    this.textfunction();
}

Cellule.prototype.textfunction = function(){
    this.test = 1;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../slimrest/andon/cellules", 
        data: "",
        success: function(msg){
            console.log("success");
            this.test = 2;
            console.log(cellule);
        }.bind(this)
    };
};

var cellule = new Cellule();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `this` in your AJAX success handles refers to the AJAX call, not to your object. Try this:

```
Cellule.prototype.textfunction = function(){
    this.test = 1;
    var _this = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "BASEURL/cellules", 
        data: "",
        success: function(msg){
            console.log("success");
            _this.test = 2;
            console.log(cellule);
        }
    });
};
```